# Magento 2 - Where is the Rest API code located?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

We call the Rest API with "/rest/V1/carts/mine".

Where is the code located in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search the api definition

```
<route url="/V1/carts/mine" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface" method="getCartForCustomer"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

The interface is provided there.

Then you need to search the class implementing the interface, or to go faster directly the method name

This is how you end up finding

`src/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php`

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getCartForCustomer($customerId)
{
    return $this->quoteRepository->getActiveForCustomer($customerId);
}
```